# Java- Capitalization within a Stack

Tags: java

I'm trying to capitalize the first character of each variable that I split. My code looks like this:

```
char firstInitial = Character.toupperCase(partOfName[0].charAt(0));
char middleInitial= Character.toupperCase(partOfName[1].charAt(0));
char lastInitial = Character.toupperCase(partOfName[2].charAt(0));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the result you're getting?  What is `partOfName?` It looks like you're not showing us all of your code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `Character.toupperCase` the error is there, `upper` should be `Upper`

Comment: @RobertHarvey Notice the answer. There is enough code to trace his answer.

Comment: Change toupperCase() to toUpperCase()

Comment: @BackSlash: Ah, sorry, my brain doesn't have intellisense.

Comment: Next time, tell us the error you are getting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method is called `toUpperCase()`, notice that the `U` is in ... upper case.

Comment: Wow, huge mistake on my part. Thanks a lot!